# How to link a file in django-cms carousel slide?

Tags: carousel, django-cms, file-link

I've created carousel in django-cms and need one slide to point to a file.
Inside link settings there are external link, internal link, e-mail and phone number but no file link.
Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Did you install django-filer?

Comment: Yes, and I want carousel-slide to be a link pointing to a file inside django-filer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.